# Enabling CDI Alternative based on environmental properties

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

I know that it is possible to configure Alternatives in the "beans.xml" file that is embedded in the EAR to be deployed.

The problem is that I use the same EAR for all the environments, and the set of properties or specific configurations are stored in some folder outside the package.

I need to configure the Alternative that I will use based on an "external beans.xml" or some similar mechanism (something that is outside the EAR).

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use alternatives if properties are outside the package.
You can write a **CDI producer** that read the properties and with `BeanManager` return the write implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see your approach, I can implement a CDI Producer to produce one or the other bean based on some properties, but... I can't see the role of BeanManager here. I can just inject the result of the producer, can you explain why the BeanManager? Thank you!

Comment: Use the BeanManager if you have to get bean instances dynamically by name, I don't know the logic behind the properties (the bean name?)